# Gitlab CI trying to run powershell when not asked to

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to build web application with gitlab-CI.
I created runner with this configuration:

```
name = "REDACTED"
  url = "REDACTED"
  token = REDACTED
  executor = "docker-windows"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "mcr.microsoft.com/powershell"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["c:\\cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Then my .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest
stages:
  - build
  - test
  
before_script:
  - "dotnet restore"
  
node_build: 
  stage: build
  only: 
    - master
  script: 
    - "echo Stage - Build started"
    - "cd ./WebApplication"
    - dir
    - dotnet build

node_test: 
  stage: test
  only: 
    - master
  script: 
    - "echo Stage - Test started"
    - "cd ./WebApplication"
    - dir
    - dotnet build
```

When the pipeline is ran, output looks like this

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.11.0 (7f7a4bb0)
  on REDACTED  REDACTED 
Preparing the "docker-windows" executor
Using Docker executor with image microsoft/dotnet:latest ...
Pulling docker image microsoft/dotnet:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:34f6f2295334d34567c67059f7c28836c79e014d0c4fadf54de3978798640003 for microsoft/dotnet:latest with digest microsoft/dotnet@sha256:61d86fc52893087df54b0579fcd9c33e144a4b3d34c543a94e6a6b376c74285d ...
Preparing environment
Running on REDACTED via 
REDACTED ...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...

Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/builds/REDACTED /c-sharp-ci-test/.git/
Checking out bbb22919 as master...

git-lfs/2.11.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.2; git 48b28d97)

Skipping Git submodules setup

Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:34f6f2295334d34567c67059f7c28836c79e014d0c4fadf54de3978798640003 for microsoft/dotnet:latest with digest microsoft/dotnet@sha256:61d86fc52893087df54b0579fcd9c33e144a4b3d34c543a94e6a6b376c74285d ...
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: container e144f05bdd00b4e744554345666afbc008ee2437c7d56bf4a98fbd949a88b1b2 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7D970B1D7: (caller: 00007FF7D96BE70B) Exception(6) tid(37c) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess] 
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"powershell -NoProfile -NoLogo -InputFormat text -OutputFormat text -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command -","User":"ContainerUser","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment"
```

When I look into log, it says it tried to run step_script stage of the job, which I never specified and it tries to run powershell. Why is that happening  and how can I get rid of it ? I supose dotnet:latest does not have powershell in it as it is not needed for building.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is always best to use a fixed tag instead of the shifting "`latest`": from one build to the next, "latest" can reference a new image version.

Second try a specific dotnet image like `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.` instead of `microsoft/dotnet:xxx`: note though they are likely to use Powershell, as seen in [their Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/src/sdk/5.0/focal/amd64/Dockerfile#L34-L45)

Try one of the [.Dotnet Samples](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/README.md) outside of GitLab to see if you can make it work manually, then include it in your `gitlab-ci.yml`.

Note: from [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 26418](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26418#note_366161230), `step_script` would be equivalent to `build_script`.